# How do i retrieve users playlists from Yahoo Music API (ASP.NET - VB)

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, yahoo, yahoo-api

I have researched quite a lot on how to retrieve user information from Yahoo Music API, i have read Open Social as well and looked at Yahoo documentation but can't find what i am looking for. Any help guys please.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to fetch the user's actual playlists, just the number of playlists they have created.

Reference: http://developer.yahoo.com/music/

The current Yahoo Music APIs are all run through [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) and don't provide any user-specific data. To access the user data, you can use the "legacy" access method which used bbAuth. In the link above, scroll to the bottom of the page for documentation links.